# How do I avoid a redirect when the user signs out in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For some reason I want to avoid being redirected after a user signs out.

here is [devise's sessions controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb).

I have already tried:

- to override `after_sign_out_path_for` but I get either `No route matches [DELETE] "/"` or `Cannot redirect to nil!`
- to `skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user` in my Sessions controller; but it still tries to redirect.

How can I just destroy the users's session without being redirect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the behaviour by overriding [Devise::SessionsController](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) and the `#destroy` method:

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def destroy
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    # the `now: true` option sets the flash for this request 
    set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_out, now: true if signed_out
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { render 'something' }
    end
  end
end
```

You also need to tell the router to route to your custom controller:

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "my_sessions" }
```

Comment: Hi @max, thank you very much for your help ! do I actually have to setup my own controller ? I generated devise's controllers using `rails generate devise:controllers users` so I am trying to implement your solution in my `Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController` that was generated in controllers/users/sessions_controllers.rb. I also added `devise_for :users` in my router so that includes `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "my_sessions" }`doesn't it ? If this is right then I still get redirected :(

Comment: `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }`

Comment: Make sure you don't have multiple calls to `devise_for` as the last one will overwrite the former. I'm guessing its something like that as you should have gotten a constant missing error.

Comment: You also don't need to generate all the controllers. Just the code you actually want to alter.

Comment: thank you ! very much ! it worked once I changed `devise_for :users` in my controller with `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations" }` as I only need sessions and registrations controllers. I removed the `format.any(*navigational_formats) { render 'something' }` line as I don't need to render anything (otherwise I'll get an error for missing template)